# How do I select just the auth token from a response in Rest Sharp with C#?

Tags: c#, authentication, restsharp

I am trying to retrieve just the auth token from my response with Rest Sharp, however, I can't seem to just isolate the code without having to pull some kind of substring shenanigans. There has to be a way to select just the access token with rest sharp. Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
 public string GetAuthWithRestSharp()
        {
            string authToken = string.Empty;
            var client = new RestClient("https://testapi.com/auth/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            var body = @"{
" + "\n" +
      @"  ""username"": ""Username"",
" + "\n" +
      @"  ""password"": ""Password"",
" + "\n" +
      @"  ""scope"": ""some.api""
" + "\n" +
      @"}";
            request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            string fullResponse = response.Content;
            // Need way to select just the auth here
            return authToken;
        }
```

I then call the method from a test that I will be using to perform a GET call with the access_token as a Bearer. Unfortunately, the response returns {"result":{"access_token": <theres a 1400 character token here>,"expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"},"success":true,"messages":null}
I just need the  part, nothing else. Is there a way to do this preferably with RestSharp or with HttpClient?

Comment: Convert response to a JObject and use that to parse out the access_token. Alternative is to use dynamic.

Comment: Please [see](https://dotnetfiddle.net/99wdqC) this simple example.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution I went with!